# SharePoint Search Keyword Query

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

Does anyone know the proper keyword or Query property to bring back ONLY sites? I am trying to create a SOAP QueryPacket for the SharePoint Search Web Service that allows users to search for sites based on their titles or descriptions.

I don't want any documents or lists or list items returned in the results.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to search for the following:

- ContentClass = "STS_Site"
- ContentClass = "STS_Web"

I put together a tool to help testing and build search queries, might help, you can find it here: http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/

Comment: My only problem with this has been that it also brings back personal sites. Have a way to exclude those?